# How to parse a file in UTF8 format correctly?

Tags: php, string, parsing, encoding, utf-8

I'm parsing an XML-Feed which contains UTF-8 encoded characters like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
  <value>Ströng</value>
</root>
```

Parsing this file with returns a malformed `StrÃ¶ng`:

```
$file = file_get_contents($path);
print_r($file);
```

Using `$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);` yields the same result.

Now I've tried to use the `utf8_encode()` function to correct the character encoding like that:

```
$file = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($path));
print_r($file);
```

But now the content gets even worse malformed: `StrÃƒÂ¶ng`. Why is that?

How to parse XML in UTF8 format correctly?

---

#### Update:

`mb_detect_encoding($file)` returns: `UTF-8` and `utf8_decode()` returns `Str?ng`.

Everything seems correct so far but it isn't?

Comment: because you need to utf_decode, or make your php script utf8

Comment: `file_get_contents` does *nothing* with the encoding. You're simply not telling the browser to handle it correctly. See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) and [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: `utf8_decode()` returns `Str?ng`

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` returns `UTF-8`, should be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the charset to UTF-8 in your document(where the print_r outputs)? 
You can do this by adding:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

to the `<head>` section.

Or in PHP add a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 2):

> Parsing this file with returns a malformed StrÃ¶ng:

That probably isn't what happens: it's very likely that your *output page* is encoded in a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1. Hence, the two-byte UTF-8 character will show up wrong even though the data is perfectly fine.

Either:

- `utf8_decode()` the result (if you in fact are using ISO-8859-1 for output)
- use `iconv()` to convert the result (if you are using a single-byte encoding other than ISO-8859-1)
- ...or change your output encoding to UTF-8 (preferable because it's the most universal solution.)